# Not able to call Web Method using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

I created a class named proxy.cs and added one method in this now want to call this from jquery. So how i can do it? Code of class is:

```
public class proxy : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]
        public string GetBigData()
        {
            return "hi welcome";//implementation code
        }
    }
```

Following Script function  not working.

```
 function test(){                  
           $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/proxy/GetBigData',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: "{}",
                success: function (response) {
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                }
            });

         }
```

Comment: GetBigData must return json and content-type application/json. maybe you need to remove ;chartset....

Comment: check in Chrome Console for any error messages!

Comment: Error in console "http://localhost:5040/proxy/GetBigData 404 (Not Found) "

Answer (score 0):

Use following Ajax Code

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: '/proxy/GetBigData',
           data: null,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           processdata: true,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           },
           error: function (message) {
               console.log("error", message);
           }
       });
```